# Linking to a Customizer control

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to set up a link that automatically takes the (admin) user inside a Control that is inside a Panel in the Customizer.

Panel:

[image: panel]

Control:

[image: control]

Here's the URL I currently have:

```
admin_url( 'customize.php?autofocus%5Bcontrol%5D=header_transparent_link' )
```

With the above in place, it takes me to inside the Header panel but not the Transparent Header control.

I also tried

```
admin_url( 'customize.php?autofocus%5Bpanel%5D=kadence_customizer_header&autofocus%5Bcontrol%5D=header_transparent_link' )
```

without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
admin_url( 'customize.php?autofocus%5Bsection%5D=kadence_customizer_transparent_header' )
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! In general it would be useful when posting code snippet answers if you could explain what you've done, but I guess in this case it's just picking the correct section name for your theme?